# Selected Java version 8 is not supported by SDK (Maximum 7)

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

New project => Sprint Initiliazr. After leaving everything to the default settings, and clicking next, the error below shows:

> Selected Java version 8 is not supported by SDK (Maximum 7)

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYxWw.png)

I've tried to update Java and installing AdoptOpenJDK as well as restarting the computer but that didn't help.

Comment: At the previous step you must choose a Project SDK that is at least 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try at first following the JDK setup guide and installing the Jetbrains JDK: [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).
If this doesn't help, select at the project creation the appropriate Jetbrains JDK manually. The Jetbrains JDK was downloaded on your machine by the Choose Runtime Plugin (as mentioned in the guide).
In Windows it's located in your user folder e.g.:
`C:\Users\xxxx\.IntelliJIdea201x.x\config\jdks\jbsdkxxxx...`

[JDK Selection under Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1HGw.png)